# Postnikov invariants of the Brauer 3-group

Tags: homotopy-theory, monoidal-categories, picard-group, brauer-groups

Given a commutative ring $k$ there is a bicategory with

- algebras over $k$ as objects,
- bimodules as morphisms,
- bimodule homomorphisms as 2-morphisms.

This is a *monoidal* bicategory, since we can take the tensor product of algebras, and everything else gets along nicely with that.

Given any monoidal bicategory we can take its **core**: that is, the sub-monoidal bicategory where we only keep *invertible* objects (invertible up to equivalence), *invertible* morphisms (invertible up to 2-isomorphism), and *invertible* 2-morphisms.

The core is a monoidal bicategory where everything is invertible in a suitably weakened sense so it's called a **3-group**.

The particular 3-group we get from a commutative ring $k$ could be called its **Brauer 3-group** and denoted $\mathbf{Br}(k)$.  It's discussed [on the $n$Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Brauer+group#RelationToCatsOfModules): there it's called the Picard 3-group of $k$ but denoted as $\mathbf{Br}(k)$.

Like any 3-group, $\mathbf{Br}(k)$ has homotopy groups which I will call $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ (though there are choices of where we start numbering).  These are well-known things:

- $\pi_1$ is the [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group) of $k$.
- $\pi_2$ is the [Picard group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group) of $k$.
- $\pi_3$ is the [group of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) of $k$.

My question is whether people have studied, or computed, the Postnikov invariants involving these things.  The simplest is the map

$$ a : \pi_1^3 \to \pi_2$$

coming from the associator in the monoidal category of $k$-algebras (with isomorphism classes of bimodules as morphisms).   Since the associator obeys the pentagon identity this is a 3-cocycle on $\pi_1$ with values in its module $\pi_2$, so it gives an element of $ H^3(\pi_1, \pi_2)$.

Is this element trivial?  If not, what is it?

But in fact $\mathbf{Br}(k)$ is not just a 3-group but also a symmetric monoidal bicategory.  So, it's what I call a **symmetric 3-group**, though some others call it a **Picard 2-category**.  These have a number of other Postnikov invariants:

- Nick Gurski, Niles Johnson, Angélica M. Osorno and Marc Stephan, [Stable Postnikov data of Picard 2-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07032).

Has anyone figured out any of these for $\mathbf{Br}(k)$?

Comment: As you point out, $\mathbf{Br}(k)$ is symmetric, and so the Postnikov invariants are (the destablizations of) stable cohomology operations. This highly constrains the question.

Comment: Br(k) is the 0th space of an HZ-module spectrum, so its Postnikov invariants are trivial (the Postnikov tower is noncanonically split).

Comment: Nice!  Is this why you can compute the groups I'm calling $\pi_i$ using Galois cohomology as $H^{3-i}(\mathrm{Gal}(K|k), K^\star)$ where $K$ is the separable closure of $k$?

Comment: They have a common explanation. Assume k a field for simplicity, let K be a separable closure, and let G = Gal(K/k). Let Br(k) denote the classifying space for your 2-category (so it's the loop space of what you're denoting by Br(k) ).  Then Br(K) carries a continuous action of G, and there's a natural map e from Br(k) to the (continuous) homotopy fixed points Br(K)^hG. The input you need is the following: 1) The map e is a homotopy equivalence (because the construction k -> Br(k) satisfies etale descent). (cont)

Comment: 2) Br(K) is an Eilenberg-MacLane space K( K^*, 2) (since the Picard and Brauer groups of a separably closed field vanish). Concretely this gives you a formula for pi_*( Br(k) ) in terms of Galois cohomology. It also tells you that Br(k) admits the structure of a topologica/simplicial abelian group (since for an Eilenberg MacLane space Br(K), choosing such a structure is equivalent to choosing a base point, and the structure survives passage to homotopy fixed points when the base point is fixed by G).

Answer (score 4):

Let me see if I understand what Jacob says in the comments. I think his argument can be summarized as: the Brauer 3-group is *étale-locally* an Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum, hence étale-locally an $\mathbb{Z}$-module spectrum, hence an $\mathbb{Z}$-module spectrum, hence the Postnikov tower splits. Do I have that right?

If so, I want to point out that the situation changes with one tweak, which is to allow superalgebras, super bimodules, etc. When $k = \mathbb{R}$ the super Brauer 3-group has a nontrivial homotopy operation $\pi_1 \to \pi_3$ given by taking the super dimension of the zeroth Hochschild homology of a superalgebra in the super Brauer group, and I computed an example of it taking a nontrivial value [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76541/what-do-the-stable-homotopy-groups-of-spheres-say-about-the-combinatorics-of-fin/196130#196130). This implies that the Postnikov tower can't split but I don't know what the $k$-invariants are. I suppose following Jacob we could try to work things out as homotopy fixed points of the $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$-action on the super Brauer 3-group over $\mathbb{C}$ but this is beyond me.

Comment: The super Morita category is a great source of examples! For another example, the $k$-invariants for $\mathbb C$, see [Dan Freed's Vienna notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/vienna.pdf) around (1.42). Another proof, computed in a slightly different way, can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11183) (see 4.3.5).